# Car class with acceleration and braking

Tags: java

I am in an intro to java class and I am having trouble with a car class that was assigned. Here are the instructions: 
Write a class named Car that has the following fields (attributes):

`yearModel` (an int which hold's the car's year model)

`make` (a String which holds the make of the car)

`speed` (an int which holds the car's current speed)

The `Car` class should have the following constructor and other methods:

`Constructor` - Accepts the car's `year` `model` and `make` as arguments.

`Accessors` (getters) for the object's `yearModel`, `make`, and `speed` fields

Methods:
`accelerate` - each time it is called, it should add 5 to the `speed` field
`brake` - each time it is called, it should subtract 5 to the `speed` field

Write a `Driver` class, the `DrivingSimulation` class, which does the following:

Prompt the user for the `yearModel`, `make`, and `speed` values of a car.
Create a `Car` object 
Call the `accelerate` method 5 times - after each call, use the `accessor` method to display the current `speed` of the car
Call the `brake` method 5 times - after each call, use the `accessor` method to display the current `speed` of the car

I got most of it done but it is not receiving the speed input that I am putting, and is instead starting from default, 0. Here is my car class

```
  package drivingsimulation;

/**
*
* @author Carlos
*/

public class Car {
private int yearModel;
private String make;
private int speed; 

public Car(int yearModel, String make) {
    this.yearModel = yearModel;
    this.make = make;
}

public int getYearModel() {
    return yearModel;
}

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public int getSpeed() {

   System.out.println("You are going " + speed + " mph");
    return speed;

}

public void accelerate() {

     speed += 5;

}


public void brake () {

     speed-=5;

}





}
```

And here is my driver class:

```
/*

package drivingsimulation;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class DrivingSimulation {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int yearModel=0;
    int speed=0;
    String make=null;


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    Car myCar = new Car(yearModel, make);

    System.out.println("What is the year of your car? ");
    yearModel = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the make of your car? ");
    make = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println("How fast is your car going?  ");
    speed = keyboard.nextInt();



    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){


        myCar.accelerate();

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a accessor for the speed class member but not setter for when you get the value from the user input in your driver class.

A method in your Car class like this:

```
public void setSpeed(int speed)
{
    this.speed = speed;
}
```

Will the set value for the car instance was user input is given.

You can call it after the user input for speed like this..

`myCar.setSpeed(speed);`

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it's not getting the speed information -- you never call `getSpeed()` on it.

Suggestions:

- Call `getSpeed()` if you want to see what the speed is.
- Get all println's out of the Car class. They should be in your main method only currently.
- Give the class a setter method for speed -- `public void setSpeed(int speed)`, and call the method.

For example, `getSpeed()` should be just

```
public int getSpeed() {
   return speed;
}
```

That's it and nothing more. But you'd call it like:

```
System.out.println("Car's speed: " + myCar.getSpeed());
```

You also don't have a `public void setSpeed(int speed)` method, and you need one, and should call it after getting the information from the user.

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely forgot the setter

Answer (score 0):

Add a `setSpeed()` setter in your Car class and call it in your DrivingSimulation class like below (also move print statement to DrivingSimulation so your Car remains modularized).

```
public class Car {

    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(int yearModel, String make) {
        this.yearModel = yearModel;
        this.make = make;
    }

    public int getYearModel() {
        return yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void accelerate() {
        speed += 5;
    }

    public void brake () {
        speed -= 5;
    }
}
```

and...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrivingSimulation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int yearModel = 0;
        String make = null;
        int speed;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        Car car = new Car(yearModel, make);

        System.out.println("What is the year of the car?");
        yearModel = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
        keyboard.nextLine(); // fixes bug - receives the Enter key without skipping make = keyboard.nextLine()
        make = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What speed is the initial speed of the car?");
        speed = keyboard.nextInt();
        car.setSpeed(speed);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
            car.accelerate();

            System.out.println("Your " + yearModel + " " + make + 
            " is traveling at " + car.getSpeed() + " MPH.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I print out the year model and make using the other class, similar to the getSpeed?

Comment: Since you would need to create a Car object, and then have it perform an action, you could copy everything in the main method over to the other class and it would work. If you just tried to modify your original print statement inside getSpeed("Your " + getYearModel() + " " + getMake()...) etc., the yearModel and make would show up as 0 and null because the object is declared in your DrivingSimulation class. I'm sure there's a way to force the Car class to print everything some other way, but I can't think how, and it probably wouldn't be an acceptable object oriented way of doing things.